# .NET framework solution started failing to due nuget misconfiguration due to CRC error

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am cloning a solution to my local PC and Newtonsoft.Json is not working anymore. This was working till yesterday but today something seemed to have gotten corrupted and is not working anymore. If I try on another machine, it works. This is what I tried:

- Deleting reference, deleting from packages.config (both from solution and from project) but the nuget won't get removed as soon as I try to uninstall due to a CRC error
- Repairing visual studio 2019
- If I remove the package from both packages.config and from references, it is still listed under the packages

I don't know what else to try. The last option would be to uninstall VS, delete any data, and then re-install and re-setting everything up again but I would like to avoid this.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to clear the NuGet cache and reinstall your dependencies?  NuGet cache and config are located at these locations :`C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages` `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NuGet` `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you set as an answer so it help other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, the cached dependencies may be corrupted and they should be cleared from the NuGet cache, and/or the NuGet config should be reset.

NuGet cache and config are located at these locations:

- `C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages`
- `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NuGet`
- `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`